# Alguien me explica el error?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Cuando lo ejecuto luego de colocar las 12 ventas, se me vuelve a repetir otra vez al 1er dato de nuevo, no me avanza, lo cual no hace la suma y tampoco saca el promedio, no entiendo que hice mal y he buscado por todos lados y aun no tengo una solución concreta para resolver el ejercicio

```
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;



int main() {
    
    int ventas [12];
    int suma = 0, mayor=0, menor=0;
    float prom;
    for (int i=0; i<12; i++){
        
        printf ("indique la venta del mes 1 \n");
        scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
        printf ("indique la venta del mes 2 \n");
        scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
        printf ("indique la venta del mes 3 \n");
        scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
        printf ("indique la venta del mes 4 \n");
        scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
        printf ("indique la venta del mes 5 \n");
        scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
        printf ("indique la venta del mes 6 \n");
        scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
        printf ("indique la venta del mes 7 \n");
        scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
        printf ("indique la venta del mes 8 \n");
        scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
        printf ("indique la venta del mes 9 \n");
        scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
        printf ("indique la venta del mes 10 \n");
        scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
        printf ("indique la venta del mes 11 \n");
        scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
        printf ("indique la venta del mes 12 \n");
        scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
    
        suma += ventas [12];}
        
    
        
    
    prom= suma / 12;{
        
        
        printf ("El promedio de las ventas fue:   ");
    }
```

Comment: todas tus ventas las estás guardando en el espacio 12, deberías de guardarla en cambio en el espacio i

Comment: Quiere decir que en vez del 12, coloco la "i"?

Comment: Si, eso dice...

Comment: Ya lo hice, y aun persiste el bucle

Comment: Actualiza los cambios a ver si son correctos

Comment: Creo que deberías de estudiar un poco más de arreglos para poder continuar con tus estudios. Recuerda que debes de tener un equilibrio entre teoría y práctica.

Comment: Es mi primera clase de arreglos bro, este es el ejercicio de practica Jajaja, pero muchas gracias por tu consejo Eduardo!!!

Answer (score 0):

> Cuando lo ejecuto luego de colocar las 12 ventas, se me vuelve a repetir otra vez al 1er dato de nuevo, no me avanza

Lógico y normal, fíjate que has creado un bucle que se repite 12 veces... y en cada iteración te pide las ventas de todo el año

```
for (int i=0; i<12; i++){ // <-- Bucle que se repite 12 veces
    
    printf ("indique la venta del mes 1 \n");  // En cada iteración pedimos mes 1
    scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
    printf ("indique la venta del mes 2 \n"); // Y mes 2, ...
    scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
    // ...
}
```

Lo que tienes que hacer es dejar que sea el bucle el que te vaya pidiendo los datos:

```
for (int i=0; i<12; i++){
    
    printf ("indique la venta del mes %d \n", i+1);
    scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
    suma += ventas[i];
}
```

Aunque ya que estás en c++, mejor usa `cin` y `cout`:

```
for (int i=0; i<12; i++){
    
    std::cout << "indique la venta del mes " << i+1 << '\n';
    std::cin >> ventas[i];
    suma += ventas[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El bucle que has escrito:

```
for (int i=0; i<12; i++){
```

Se lee así: "*Partiendo de una `i` con valor `0`, mientras `i` sea menor a `12` aumenta `i` en uno en cada vuelta*". Todo lo que haya dentro del bucle se repetirá "*mientras `i` sea menor a `12`*", eso quiere decir que **todo el código entre las llaves de apertura (`{`) y cierre (`}`)** del bucle se repetirá "*mientras `i` sea menor a `12`*".

En otras palabras, este código **se repetirá doce veces**:

```
                        {
    printf ("indique la venta del mes 1 \n");
    scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
    printf ("indique la venta del mes 2 \n");
    scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
    printf ("indique la venta del mes 3 \n");
    scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
    printf ("indique la venta del mes 4 \n");
    scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
    printf ("indique la venta del mes 5 \n");
    scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
    printf ("indique la venta del mes 6 \n");
    scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
    printf ("indique la venta del mes 7 \n");
    scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
    printf ("indique la venta del mes 8 \n");
    scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
    printf ("indique la venta del mes 9 \n");
    scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
    printf ("indique la venta del mes 10 \n");
    scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
    printf ("indique la venta del mes 11 \n");
    scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);
    printf ("indique la venta del mes 12 \n");
    scanf ("%d", &ventas [i]);

    suma += ventas [12];
}
```

Seguramente querías hacer esto:

```
for (int i=0; i<12; i++){
    printf ("indique la venta del mes %d\n", i + 1);
    scanf ("%d", &ventas[i]);
    suma += ventas[i];
}
```

Pero como estás programando en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), lo que realmente **DEBES** hacer es esto:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int ventas[12];
    int suma = 0;

    int mes = 1;
    for (auto &venta : ventas)
    {
        cout << "indique la venta del mes 1 \n";
        cin >> venta;
        suma += venta
    }

    cout << "El promedio de las ventas fue: " << venta / float(std::extent_v<decltype(ventas)>);

    return 0;
}
```